# Calculating trend for an array of numbers

Tags: linear, trend

I have a website on golf statistics and wanted to calculate the trend for various things.

E.g. for fairways hit off the tee, let's say I have values = `[0.5, 0.67, 0.8, 0.5, 0.4]` (meaning the percentage of fairways hit). I want to calculate the trend in that particular category. What I mean by trend, is just simply, is the player getting better or worse, or in general terms, are the numbers trending upward or downward for that particular category.

I found a function written in Ruby that calculated the slope for these values as `-0.037` or `-3.7%`.

Is this an accurate value for the trend or do I need some other function?

Comment: Yes that is the accurate value for the trend and it shows that he is getting worse as time goes by

Comment: Can you share the function?

Comment: @ThomasValadez https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51440999/finding-data-trendlines-with-ruby